# jQuery .hasClass() inside each() on children() is not working "is not a function"

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate through children of a div and figure out which one has the `is-active` class:

```
$('.childrenContainerSelector').children().each(child => console.log(child.hasClass('is-active'));
```

But when I run the code, I get the `hasClass() is not a function` error.

If I run just:

```
$('.childrenContainerSelector').children()
```

as an output, I do get the correct children.

Comment: please post the HTML and maybe we can find a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

The arguments for the callback function are `(Integer index, Element element)` so you're trying to call `hasClass()` on an `int`.

Note that the second arg is an `Element` and not `jQuery` so if you wanted to use jQuery methods, you'd need to wrap it

```js
$('.childrenContainerSelector').children().each((i, child) => 
  console.log($(child).hasClass('is-active'))
```

Alternately, use the built-in [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) methods

```js
child.classList.contains("is-active")
```

---

If you're just after the children with the `is-active` class, why not use

```js
const activeChildren = $(".childrenContainerSelector > .is-active")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Phil as already clearly pointed out, the first argument is `index`. Also bear in mind that `.hasClass()` is a jQuery method; it's applied on a jQuery collection, not a DOM element. So you can use either `$(this).hasClass()` or `$(child).hasClass()` where `child` is the second element.

To get all children having class `.is-active` use:

```
$('.childrenContainerSelector > .is-active').each((i,child) => {
    //your code
    console.log( $(child).hasClass('is-active'); //You know it already has .. OR
    console.log( %(this).hasClass('is-active');
});
```

Or:

```
$('.childrenContainerSelector').children().filter('.is-active').each((i,child) => {
    //your code
});
```